# Stretchable constants

Tags: c++

[This guideline](https://sceweb.uhcl.edu/helm/RationalUnifiedProcess/manuals/cpp/cpp.htm) talks about *stretchable constants*:

> Use "stretchable" constants whenever possible
>
> Stretchable constants avoid problems with word-size variations.

It also provides an example:

```cpp
const int all_ones = ~0;
const int last_3_bits = ~0x7;
```

What are *stretchable constants*?

Comment: What would the value of `~0` be if `int` was 16 bit, and what if it is 32 bit?

Comment: I've never heard of the term before. But I'm guessing it means to use `~0` instead hard coding `0xFFFFFFFF` (or whatever number of `F` your platform needs, which I guess is the whole point).

Comment: `const int aallll__oonneess` is no longer a valid identifier.  Clearly not stretchable that way.

Comment: he recommends to use `~0` instead `0xffffffff` which assumes size of the `int`. IMO he should use name "stretchable literals".

Comment: What about non-stretchable ones `unsigned int i = ~0xFFFFFFFF;`?

Comment: Be warned that the type of the variable can differ from that of the literal (though not in this case), and sign extension may or may not do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old recommendation. You can recognize this also because the text is using `const` and not `constexpr`.

And the guy is using datatype `int`. And that is the tricky part. Int can be 2, 4, 8 or maybe in the future 16 Bytes.

Stretchable means, you have a small (or whatever data type) and the assigned value will be the same, regardless of the implementation of the data type. If you want to have all bits set, and you will use `~0`, then this will work with an 8 bit or 16 bit or 32 bit or 64 bit value. Hence the word "stretching".

This should make software safer. But for this requirement, there are other measures. For safe software, nobody would use `int`. There are for example the MISRA rules that require, not to use any build in data type. And you can use  types. That's anyway better.

So "stretching" means: Same value for stretched (bigger) variable types.

Comment: CHAR_BIT doesn't *have* to be 8... ;-)